# Is there like an established way of distributing non-ruby scripts with rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I add a bash script as an executable in a gem, installing the gem causes the executable to get wrapped in something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'my_bash_script' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'my_bash_script', version
load Gem.bin_path('my_bash_script', 'my_bash_script', version)
```

This makes it dysfunctional because the ruby interpreter obviously doesn't speak bash.

What's a good way of dealing with this? Can I turn the wrapping off (preferable, as bash starts about 12 times faster than the YARV ruby interpreter), or do I need to wrap my bash in ruby in order for the generated load wrapper to be happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following answer in one of the rubygem repo's [ticket discussions](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/88).

*I don't know of a good way to do this that works across platforms and makes sense.
Rubygems is for ruby. If a file is in your gem's bindir and listed as a gem executable, it should be ruby. If your gem has "special needs" then it should do it out of band, like create a Rakefile that does your special steps for you and list the Rakefile as an extension in the spec. Or just use a post-install message telling people to install with --no-wrapper.*

Also I found the following comment in [rubygems specification documentation](https://github.com/olbrich/rubygems/commit/316ae3ff829da4b3a60f61ca209ebbb9d39f0039).

*#
   # For example, the rake gem has rake as an executable. You don’t specify the
   # full path (as in bin/rake); all application-style files are expected to be
-  # found in bindir.
+  # found in bindir.  These files must be executable ruby files.  Files that
+  # use bash or other interpreters will not work.
   #*

Hope this information helps.

Comment: I found it too. But since SO is mainly about copying and pasting anyway ... :D

Comment: How will we know if you found your answer long time back?. I hope you are aware that you can answer your own questions :)

Comment: Also I never claimed it to be my own. I have given links to where I found the italicized text in this answer.

Comment: Just in case you didn't get it, the three dots stand for ", I'm upvoting and accepting your answer"